# Catching User Input from Form HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms

I'm currently trying to catch input data from a form and storing that data into an array of objects that can then summarize the data caught in the console. On top of this, I'm trying to run the function to store that data using a traditional DOM event handler per the instructions for my assignment.

The end goal with the JS is to use var t to get the element of the submit button by the ID 'contactSubButton' and run the function contactInfo onsubmit...

However, no matter what I try I get this message in the console at the line for the 't.addEventListener'....

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

```js
var t = document.getElementById("contactSubButton");
t.addEventListener('click', contactInfo());

function contactInfo(fName, lName, email, country, subject) {
  fName = document.getElementById('fname').value;
  lName = document.getElementById('lname').value;
  email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  country = document.getElementById('country').value;
  subject = document.getElementById('subject').value;

  for (i = 0;; i++) {
    var subInfo = [fName, lName, email, country, subject]
  }

  console.log('Your submission details are:' < br > 'First Name: ' + fName)
}
```

```html
<div id="form">
  <form>
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your first name...">

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name....">

    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Please enter your email...">

    <label for="country">Country</label>
    <select id="country" name="country">
      <option value="usa">United States</option>
      <option value="canada">Canada</option>
      <option value="mexico">Mexico</option>
    </select>

    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="How can we help?"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="contactSubButton">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset Form">

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: you have to make sure the DOM already loaded before you find the element

Comment: Also you have a loop that never finishes `for (i = 0;; i++) {`

Comment: Also you pass unnecessary variables here `contactInfo(fName, lName, email, country, subject) {`

Comment: Also you assign the event listener incorrectly. You need `t.addEventListener('click', contactInfo);` without the `()`

Comment: Also the loop does nothing useful `var subInfo = [fName, lName, email, country, subject]`

Comment: @the91end how exactly do I verify that the DOM has already loaded? I'm very limited in my knowledge of DOM thus far.

Comment: @mplungjan I haven't had a chance to work through my issues with the loop yet, I was first trying to resolve the issue with it not catching the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you have a loop that never finishes `for (i = 0;; i++) {`
- you pass unnecessary variables here `contactInfo(fName, lName, email, country, subject) {`
- you assign the event listener incorrectly. You need `t.addEventListener('click', contactInfo);` without the `()`
- your quotes are wrong in the `console.log('Your submission details are:' < br > 'First Name: ' + fName)`

I think you want this

- I use the submit event
- I cancel the submit event if user presses cancel

```js
function contactInfo(event) { // passing the submit event
  let fName = document.getElementById('fname').value,
    lName = document.getElementById('lname').value,
    email = document.getElementById('email').value,
    country = document.getElementById('country').value,
    subject = document.getElementById('subject').value;

  const text = `Your submission details are:
    First Name: ${fName}
    Last Name:  ${lName}
    Email:      ${email}
    Country:    ${country}
    Subject:    ${subject}
    Send this now?`
  
  if (!confirm(text)) event.preventDefault(); // stop submission by cancelling the event passed
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() { // when page loads
  document.getElementById("contactForm").addEventListener('submit', contactInfo);

});
```

```html
<div id="form">
  <form id="contactForm">
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your first name...">

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name....">

    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Please enter your email...">

    <label for="country">Country</label>
    <select id="country" name="country">
      <option value="usa">United States</option>
      <option value="canada">Canada</option>
      <option value="mexico">Mexico</option>
    </select>

    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="How can we help?"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="contactSubButton">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset Form">

  </form>
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me. Can you just elaborate on what exactly the 'e' passed into the function and the e.preventDefault do in this scenario?

Comment: The e is the submit event and event.preventDefault() is cancelling that event

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

Html:

```
<form method="post" id="myForm">
   <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Your first name...">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener ("submit", function (evt) {
   evt.preventDefault();
   var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('myForm'))
   console.log('Your submission details are:' < br > 'First Name: ' + formData.get('firstname'))
});
```